# How do I reduce color bending on hair when changing clothing color beneath via Hue?

Tags: photoshop, color-correction, hair, hue

I'm using Hue/Saturation to change the color of the clothes but whenever I encounter long hair on clothes I get into trouble with the color bending on the edges of the hair. Its a mix of purple and grey. How can I fix it that?

[image]

[image]

The screenshots above are from Photoshop, this one is from Lightroom without development on the left, the raw format and on the right the developed file that was then sent to PS.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the original image without the artifacts?

Comment: I have added one more screenshot. I have this problem with all images in which I try to change the underlying color of clothing beneath hairs.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do somewhat better by using luminosity masks... I used "apply image" to create the mask and then edited the mask for contrast. But there are many ways of creating luminosity masks; including some free plugins/actions.

This is what one of the masks looked like.
[image]

And this is my result next to your result.

[image]